# Laravel 4 When updating model and hit save, only update the updated_at column

Tags: php, laravel-4, timestamp

I just found out, when updating a model (let's say a `$post` model), i.e. updating body text and the title and hit save, it automaticly updates the created_at column, but i would like it to ONLY update the updated_at column.

I've searched around quite a while before asking, so i know `$post->touch()` only updated the timestamps and not the rest. And when setting `protected $timestamp = false;` in my post model, it simply disables the timestamp update when updating/saving.

For those who wonder, i am currently still using `$post->save();` to update a post.

So, is there anyone who knows how to keep the `created_at` (which will be set when creating the post) and update the `updated_at` when updating/editing the post?

My post update() controller function:

```
public function update($slug)
{
    $post                   = Post::byslug($slug);
    $post->concept          = Input::get('concept');
    $post->title            = Input::get('title');
    $post->slug             = Str::slug(Input::get('title'));
    $post->body             = Input::get('body');
    $post->metatitle        = 'My Website |' . Input::get('title');
    $post->metadescription  = Input::get('body');
    $post->robots           = Input::get('robots');
    $post->ogtitle          = 'My Website |' . Input::get('title');
    $post->ogdescription    = Input::get('body');
    $post->ogsitename       = 'My Website';
    $post->ogurl            = Str::slug(Input::get('title'));
    $post->ogtype           = Input::get('ogtype');

    if(Input::hasFile('file'))
    {
        $file               = Input::file('file');
        $destinationPath    = 'uploads/images/posts/';
        $filename           = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $upload_success     = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $post->image        = str_replace('\\', '/', $upload_success);
        $post->ogimage      = str_replace('\\', '/', $upload_success);
    }
    if($post->save())
    {
        return Redirect::route('admin.blog.index')
        ->with('post', $post);
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('admin.blog.edit')
        ->with('post', $post)
        ->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth let you think that update alters `created_at` column? It certainly does not, so show your code and the results.

Comment: I checked my DB and the 'created_at' column was updated to todays date.So it certainly does..

Comment: Like I said, show the code if you want any help with your issue.

Comment: do this: `if($post->save()) { return DB::getQueryLog();}` and check the executed queries.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue.
the problem was with mysql behavior on table creation.
i created timestap field like this

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
...
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
...
```

and mysql converted it to the field with automatic autoupdating (i don't know why - but it did - i checked with phpmyadmin). so laravel did not updated the field - it was mysql himself.
i changed field creation to

```
... `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ...
```

and it helped. no "autoupdated dates" any more.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself. Vasiliy's answer got me where I needed to be, but it lacked a rather important detail. The option that you want to override is the on update for the column, not the default. What I found in mine, when I ran

```
show create table <table_name>
```

I found:

```
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ON UPDATE current_timestamp.
```

I simply did two alter table commands, one to remove the on update from created at, and another to add it to the updated_at column.

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHANGE created_at created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHANGE updated_at updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ON UPDATE current_timestamp;
```

Making these changes solved my problem, so as Jarek said, it's not actually a Laravel problem. My guess is if you had used a migration, Laravel would create these columns correctly. (I don't yet use migrations myself, hence why I likely ran into the issue as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Small update to @EpicWally - I dont think you need to add UPDATE to the updated_at column - laravel takes care of that internally.

Also - if you want to do this via a migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `posts` CHANGE `created_at` `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00"');
    });
}
```